# Taylor formula exercice

Tags: implicit-function-theorem

1. Let the curve $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$, given by $\gamma(t)=(t,t^2,t^3)$. Find the (with two decimal numbers) the nearest point $C$ to $(1,0,0)$.

In this exercise do I have to use Taylor formula?

Comment: In the first exercice, you have to minimize the distance $d$ between point $(1,0,0)$ and the general point of the curve, i.e., minimize $d^2$, the square of the distance, which amounts to minimize $f(t)=(1-t)^2+t^4+t^6$, which is obtained by setting its derivative $f'(t)=0$, thus $t=0.5418...$.

Comment: After JeanMarie's comment, the second derivative being $f''(t)=2+12t^2+30t^4$, it is always positive. So, the solution is a minimum.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So the point is $\gamma(0,5418)$?

Comment: Do you have any hint for the other question? Thanks